# Grab css property attached to a div element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a basic CSS problem, that I don't know is really a basic or is it something else.

Here is the **HTML**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class='test1'>Test1</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the **CSS**.

```
.test1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

As we can see I have an `div` element having a class `test1` on it with **margin** property as `5px`.
Now if I want to get the **margin** value on the `div` element how will I get it?

And just a tip, writing below JS won't do anything, as there is no style attribute in the `div`, **margin** is added to the div by **css class test1.**

```
const test1 = document.getElementsByClassName("test1")[0];
console.log(test1.style.margin);
```

Here is the [JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/vepeyinimo/6/edit?html,css,js,console,output) for the above scenerio.

Comment: As mentioned in the Question there is no style atrribute at all in the div element, so writing document.getElementsByClassName("test1")[0].style.margin won't work.

Comment: @Zuber what are you trying to say, I need to grab the margin property in the css attached to the div.

Comment: @Zuber that what question is I don't want to give style attribute, just read the Question carefully and all the comments then please write your thoughts on it.

Comment: @Zuber please just read the last few lines starting from And just a tip, writing below JS won't do anything, as there is no style attribute in the div, margin is added to the div by css class test1. That is what I am trying to say on those lines, that's why the answer posted doesn't involve adding inline style attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [**`Window.getComputedStyle()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle):

> The `Window.getComputedStyle()` method returns an object containing the values of all CSS properties of an element, after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain. Individual CSS property values are accessed through APIs provided by the object, or by indexing with CSS property names.

```js
const test1 = document.getElementsByClassName("test1")[0];
console.log(getComputedStyle(test1).margin);
```

```css
.test1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='test1'>Test1</div>
```

Comment: Great @Mamun it works with getComputedStyle().

Comment: You were faster, I was writing the same answer. Nice job